# How are columns in SharePoint connected to CAML with regards to data submission?

Tags: infopath, javascript, caml, data, connection

I am trying to make an alteration to an infopath form that was created to submit data to sharepoint. I added a dropdown box and want to submit that data to sharepoint. The submission has been completed prior to my arrival and has been coded with javascript.

I can pick up the data.

```
var bocaCheck = root.selectSingleNode("my:boca").text;
```

then added

```
batch.selectSingleNode("/Batch/Method/Field[@Name='Boca']").text = bocaCheck;
```

with updated CAML

```
<Field Name="Boca" />
```

created the column "Boca" in the SharePoint list

My issue is that for some reason when I submit the data it populates another column in SharePoint called "Printing Area." Anyone know why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the new column is mapped to populate the column Printing Area rather than your new Boca field. This is achieved using Property Promotion. To check this do the following.
Are you using InfoPath 2010 or InfoPath 2013?

For 2013 (sorry that's what I have on my machine at the moment)

- Open the InfoPath form in Design mode
- Click File > Info >  Advanced Form Options > Property Promotion
- The Boca Column should have an entry, click Modify and check which column its being mapped to, I would think it would be the Printing Area column, change this to your Boca Column.